# Why does my react app not re-render when I am using useState and setting mutated object to state. But it is re-rendering in the case of setState

Tags: reactjs

I have written same piece of logic using setState and useState.

In case of setState it's re-rendering the UI but that is not the case with useState.

[See sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-water-jx493?file=/src/App.js)

With a class component using setState:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { name: "ashutosh" };

  handleClick = () => {
    const newObj = this.state;
    newObj.name = "Nrew";
    console.log(newObj === this.state);
    this.setState(newObj);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{JSON.stringify(this.state.name)}</h1>
        <h2 onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Start editing to see some magic happen!
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using a functional component and  `useState` hook:

```
export default function App() {
  const [nameObj, setNameObj] = React.useState({ name: "ashutosh" });

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newObj = nameObj;
    newObj.name = "New";
    setNameObj(newObj);
  };
  console.log("nameObj", nameObj);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(nameObj.name)}</h1>
      <h2 onClick={handleClick}>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the app is not re-rendering is that you are mutating the original state object, and then passing that original object back in to `setNameObj`.

With the new hooks api, you have to make sure you create a new object when you are updating the state:

```
export default function App() {
  const [nameObj, setNameObj] = React.useState({ name: "ashutosh" });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(nameObj.name)}</h1>
      <h2 onClick={() => setNameObj({ name: "Nrew" })}>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but when I am not setting the new object in useState then it should work as it is working in case of class based Components

Comment: Directly mutating the state object is something that you are not meant to do in React.

When the new Hooks api (`useState`) was developed for functional components, they added an `Object.is` check to optimise for if it was still the same object being used. This is why you need to make a new object.

Doing the wrong thing and then updating with `setState` still works for class components as they couldn't make that change without breaking previously written projects, but going forwards they have prevented you from being able to do this.

Comment: A better solution would be to just have a string for the name-state, then you avoid the complexity and performance overhead of using an object.